# Documenting microcontroller peripheral configuration register settings?

Tags: c++, microcontroller

I'm currently writing code to configure and interact with a particular peripheral over I2C. Configuring all of the desired features on the device, of course, requires setting a number of registers to specific values. I am already using macros in the form of `#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0 0xEE` to organize my accesses of the device memory, but the byte(s) to be written are currently just magic numbers. How should the bits or vectors within each memory location be described/documented to make the configuration of the device understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use macros to define the register settings as well as the register address.  For example, imagine the value of register NAME0 is a bit field containing two individual bits for enabling THIS and THAT.  And it also contains a two-bit field for selecting one of four MODEs.

```
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_ADDR 0xEE
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_ENABLE_THIS 0x01
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_ENABLE_THAT 0x02
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_MODE0 0x00
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_MODE1 0x04
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_MODE2 0x08
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_MODE3 0x0C
```

Then you build the value that you want to assign to the register by bitwise-ORing together a macro for each field within the register.

```
// This value enables THIS, disables THAT, and selects MODE1
(DEVICE_REG_NAME0_ENABLE_THIS | DEVICE_REG_NAME0_MODE1)

// This value disables THIS, enables THAT, and selects MODE2
(DEVICE_REG_NAME0_ENABLE_THAT | DEVICE_REG_NAME0_MODE2)
```

If you want to get even more explicit with the disable bits then you could define these extra macros.

```
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_DISABLE_THIS 0x00
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_DISABLE_THAT 0x00
```

The names for the individual bits and fields of the register value should reflect the names used in the data sheet.

Update:  If you have a multi-bit field that represents an integer value and you don't want to define a macro for every possible value then you could use a  single macro to define the shift amount.  For example, lets add another DEBOUNCE field in bits 4 through 6 that represent an integer period with a value between 0 and 7.

```
#define DEVICE_REG_NAME0_DEBOUNCE_SHIFT 4
```

Given an integer variable `debounce` representing the desired value (unshifted), you create the corresponding register value like this

```
(debounce << DEVICE_REG_NAME0_DEBOUNCE_SHIFT)
```

And you can bitwise-OR that quantity with the macros for the other register fields.

Comment: So there's no compact way to specify this? Additionally, how to handle vectors within the register? A piece of sample code I saw just had a lengthy comment explaining where the final hex constant came from rather than macros for the bits in the register.

Comment: Since this is C++, you could change all the `#define` to `const uint8_t` and assign the values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compact".  If you mean executable code, know that the pre-processor will perform macro expansion and perform the bitwise-OR operation at compile time.  So this solution creates no more executable code than a magic number solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "vector".  Perhaps you should post a link to the device data sheet and point out the register and vector field that you are referring to.

Comment: By "compact" I mean in code-space. I understand that the macro expansion will produce a nice complied result, but the macros are lengthy. By "vector" I mean a group of bits in a byte that are one value. For example, 3 bits that control the size of a debounce counter.

Comment: In my example, the MODE field is a two-bit field that qualifies as a vector by your definition.  The MODE field occupies bits 2 and 3.  It has four possible values, which when shifted to the appropriate bits equal 0x00, 0x04, 0x08, or 0x0C.

Comment: To me, "code space" refers to executable code size.  The executable code size for the macro solution is no bigger than the magic number solution.  If you mean source code size then you can use shorter macro names to your preference.  There is a trade-off between brevity and clarity.  From your question the goal is code that describes/documents in a manner that is understandable.  So in my answer brevity was not considered.